# Cannot drag items into a cloned sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I hope you can understand my case because my english is a little weak. I have items 1,2 and 3 that need to be placed into a container by dragging them. This works fine, but the problem appears when I create cloned containers that I created. I will include the demo in the comments section.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/psgL2on9

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution, the problem was when new container is created you lose the `sortable` function, so you have to recall it

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
console.log('end tracking');
    $('.container').sortable();  
}
```